# Override <connectionStrings> during release pipeline

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, azure-devops, web-config, connection-string, azure-pipelines

My `Web.config` looks like this:

```
<connectionStrings configSource="secretConnectionStrings.config">
  </connectionStrings>
```

`secretConnectionStrings.config` stores the DB connection string with the password and is not in source control.

I can see the following in the "Deploy Azure App Service" task:

[image: configuration settings]

How can I update my VSTS release pipeline so that the `<connectionStrings>` section is replaced with a connection string (including password) which I supply?

My repo is public which is why I don't want the password in there, and only trusted people have access to the VSTS account used to deploy.

Comment: You should be able to make this work with the [File transforms and variable substitution reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=vsts). Also, you could have a look at [MSI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely the answer you're looking for, but still an answer to your problem: have a look at what the Azure App Service [ConnectionStrings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure#connection-strings) settings under [Application Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure#application-settings) do:

> For .NET apps, these connection strings are injected into your .NET configuration connectionStrings settings at runtime, overriding existing entries where the key equals the linked database name.

Using this in a smart way enables you to have the setting just be present on the App Service, without the release pipeline even having to know them.

You could also, of course, have the release pipeline update the settings on the App Service. Because you can do XML Transformations with the `Azure App Service Deploy` task, you can remove the external file reference. Or remove it alltogether.

*Also, have a look at [my comment on your post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52941117/override-connectionstrings-during-release-pipeline#comment92793657_52941117)*